# Is there any clear picture or drawing, of a Wright brothers' plane, published before August 12, 1908?

Tags: aviation-history

Based on a video and two articles, one form May 1904, and the other from December 1951, both of them quoting people who personally knew the Wright brothers (see the explanations below), I have reached the conclusion that the oldest clear published photos of a Wright powered flying machine appeared in French newspapers on August 12, 1908, and the oldest unclear pictures in the Scientific American, on May 30, 1908. Another conclusion would be that the Wright brothers could not have taken any picture, at Kitty Hawk, North Carolina, of one of their airplanes in flight, before April-May 1908.

Question: Are there newspapers, magazines, etc., older than Aug, 12, 1908, that show a Wright airplane on the ground or flying? I am looking for them in archives but I can not find anything.

[image]

Video link: [**The Wright brothers and their imaginary 1903-1905 flights**](https://youtu.be/-LNUsP-ei9w)

The Wright brothers did not even finish the 1903 plane at Kitty Hawk, NC. Flyer 1 never flew as can be seen in the following 1904 article:

The Wilmington Messenger, Wilmington, North Carolina, May 26, 1904, col. 1, p. 6.

> Elizabeth City Economist: A gentleman visiting this city whose home is
> in Kitty Hawk, is responsible for the assertion that the Wright
> brothers, of airship fame, will return to Kitty Hawk in the near
> future and resume work on their aerial monster. According to this
> gentleman the airship has never been removed from Kitty Hawk and
> nearly all the interviews published in the papers of Norfolk have been
> erroneous in this respect. This gentleman has assisted the Wrights in
> all their work and has a general supervision of their property during
> their absence. **He says that they have not completed the ship and
> that they will return some time within the next month and resume their
> work**. A story is current that they will complete the ship and make
> the trip from here to St. Louis sometime this fall.

The text says that, according to a man that worked for the Wrights and took care of their things left behind at Kitty Hawk, the two inventors hadn't finished Flyer I as of May 26, 1904. In conclusion, this machine did not fly on December 17, 1903!

[image: The true date of the above picture is May 1908 not December 17, 1903]

**The true date of the above picture is May 1908 not December 17, 1903.**

The fact that the photo was taken in May 1908 is also supported by the 1951 declaration of Alpheus W. Drinkwater, a man who knew the Wright brothers.

> Wilbur and Orville Wright are credited with making their first powered
> flight in a heavier-than-air machine on Dec. 17, 1903. But Alpheus W.
> Drinkwater, 76 years old, who sent the telegraph message ushering in
> the air age, **said the brothers only “glided” off Kill Devil Hill that
> day. Their ﬁrst real flight came on May 6, 1908**, he said. (Source: New York Times, Dec. 17, 1951.)

As a note: The Wrights left Kitty Hawk, North Carolina, in December 1903 and only came back in April 1908.

Comment: resource location is off topic as defined by the [help center](/help/on-topic)

Comment: This is the definition of "Resource location": 
" Where to buy a specific part, "Which headset is the best?", Where can I get a feed of flight-related data? " My question is about the history of aviation (an allowed subject) and has nothing to do with Resource location. Most questions in connection with the history of aviation can not be correctly and precisely answered without quoting old documents in archives.

Comment: I agree.  It is a good question.  I never knew there was any controversy.  And the doubts seem credible...

Comment: It's promoting a hoax, a debunked "conspiracy theory" type of revisionist history. One link to one ridiculous video is far from "credible" - there are Flat Earth videos with as much credibility as that. Let's don't taint AV.SE with this garbage.

Comment: At best this may belong on Skeptics.SE, but not here.

Comment: OK, I am all in favor of not propagating unrealistic conspiracy theories, but shouldn't we strive to debunk at every opportunity?  I had honestly never heard of this controversy before, but why not just answer the question with a link to the debunking?  Conspiracy theories thrive on being shut down without a reasonable counter...

Comment: @MichaelHall That's exactly the purpose of the site I mentioned, otherwise this is a debate here and not really well suited.

Comment: @Ron Beyer, I understand what you are saying and agree to a point, but the title question is really a simple yes or no question that could be put to bed forever easily enough for anybody stumbling on this site.  i.e. "Yes, and here it is: __" would kill the controversy forever, right?  Closing the question just adds fuel...

Comment: @RonBeyer, I found the same small article, that says the Wrights did not finish Flyer 1 in 1903, in: The Daily Free Press, Kinston, North Carolina, May 27, 1904, col. 6, pag. 1. (https://www.newspapers.com/ you can search for the article using the free trial option). If the Wrights flew in December 1903, such articles should not exist. Forget about the video (also it contains interesting pictures in French newspapers, I have never seen before). Both the May 1904 and Dec. 1951 articles are authentic. There is no conspiracy theory here. They are not written by the Flat Earth people.

Comment: Re - "The true date of the above picture is May 1908 not December 17, 1903."-- that's ridiculous.  Why has this question not been heavily dv'd?

Comment: Dozens and dozens, or more likely hundreds, of blatantly false accounts of the Wrights' activities may be found in the newspapers of the time.  And the point is?

Comment: @quietflyer , There is only one contemporary false account (denied by the Wrights on January 6, 1904) for the interval of interest 1903-1905. It is an article that claimed the 1903 machine flew 3 miles and had a propeller placed under the plane and another behind the wings. The story propagated in the newspapers across the US. This is the article: “Flying Machine Soars 3 Miles in Teeth of High Wind Over Sand Hills and Waves at Kitty Hawk on Carolina Coast”, Virginian-Pilot, Norfolk, Dec. 18, 1903, col. 7, pag. 1. (www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.05001/?sp=12).

Comment: @RobertWerner -- thanks for setting me straight.  My impression was very different, based I guess on faulty recollections of things I had read some years back in books about the Wrights.

Comment: Related --https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/86778/34686 , https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/81263/34686

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any picture printed before August 1908 and showing a fully recognizable Wright plane, beyond any doubt.

As a remark, there exists a drawing, published in L'Auto, a French newspaper, on December 24, 1905, but it is just a rough sketch. However, this caricature is the closest drawing to what would become to be known as the Wright planes, much later, starting with August 1908.

As an explanation: Robert Coquelle, a French journalist, while in the United States for other purposes, visited the Wright brothers, did not see any plane and once back in France he made fun of them in L'Auto in an article titled: "The conquest of the air by two bicycle dealers". Coquelle does not clearly explain the origin of the drawing below that illustrates his article.

[image: The true aeroplane of the Wright brothers]

The true aeroplane of the Wright brothers.

Source: [1905-12-24, Robert Coquelle, “La Conquête de l’Air par deux Marchands de Cycles. Comment un ancien champion cycliste, Johanny S. Johnson, introduisit un rédacteur de « l’Auto » dans l’atelier des frères Wright.”, L’Auto, Paris, Saturday, December 24, 1905.](https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.05001/?sp=33)

Comment: Funny article, funny subtitles: "An 1 hour and  40 min flight ended with a rapid descent amid little black pigs. Doubts are no longer allowed!". (Source: https://www.loc.gov/resource/mwright.05001/?sp=34).

Comment: Related -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/77074/34686

Comment: So all the photos from https://www.wright-brothers.org/Information_Desk/Just_the_Facts/Airplanes/Flyer_I.htm (linked in the linked Q) are fake or antedated? I see this Q seem to asking about *published* pictures, so I guess what the Q really meant is when those were published.

Answer (score 2):

Are you seriously concluding that the Wright brothers did not fly until 1908 based on the absence of a published picture and a couple of outlier statements?

In the past, it has been all too easy for someone to pull a couple of articles out of the air and assert that our understanding of history is wrong. However, in the age of the internet, this is no longer true.  If you go to [Chronicling America](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/) a free newspaper database and search for "Wright brothers" for the period 1903 to 1908, you will get thousands of hits. If you search for the period 1903 to 1904, you will get hundreds of hits describing the 1903 flight.

For example, a 1907 article called "The Reality of the Airship" which appeared in the Sunday Star, Washington, DC (6/2/1907), part 4, p. 4, quotes at great length a speech given by Sir Alexander Graham Bell - a competitor to the Wright brothers. He states "Their machine has flown not once simply, but many times, and in the presence of witnesses, so that there can be no doubt that the first successful flying machine has at last appeared." He then describes the Dayton flights in great detail.

Given all those contemporary articles and eyewitness accounts, I believe that the burden of proof is on you to prove that all those statements were lies before you can seriously assert that the Wright brothers did not fly until 1908.

Comment: It’s worth bearing in mind that photography in 1903 was only a small step away from having a portrait painted and was ill-suited to a transient event with significant movement.  It might be considered analogous to questioning whether a present day event took place because it wasn’t enshrined in a non-fungible asset.

Comment: After searching "Chronicling America" for a few months, I have reached the conclusion that there is nothing there of any value regarding the 1903-1905 powered flights of the Wright brothers. The most accurate and documented articles repeat again and again the stories launched by the Wright brothers themselves. Alexander Graham Bell just read "The statement of the Wrights to the Aero Club of America (dated March 12, 1906)" in which the two inventors claimed a number o long flights seen by 18 witnesses, all named. (see: https://transcription.si.edu/view/13664/NASM-NASM.XXXX.0376-M0000104-00020).

Comment: Phil Crowther, I am still waiting to see  that "clear picture or drawing, of a Wright brothers' plane, published before August 12, 1908". I was unable to find it in the archive "Chronicling America".

Comment: Regarding the the absence of a clear drawing, I am a bit confused because in your previous post, you showed the drawing published in 1906.  While not a work of art, it does clearly show the basic shape of the airplane, the propellers, chains and track they used.  Their reluctance to publish the 1903 picture in 1903 is understandable because they were attempting to patent their wing-warping mechanism and would not have wanted the public to see the mechanism until the patent was granted.